# Add a line break in sqlcmd output

Tags: sql-server, cmd, sqlcmd

I am working with SQL Server 2019 on Windows. I have a SQL script (`.sql` file) which I run from the command prompt using `sqlcmd`.

This is the script:

```
use master
go
select '$(SQLCMDWORKSTATION)' 'SQLCMDWORKSTATION';
```

When I run it I get the output:

```
Changed database context to 'master'.
SQLCMDWORKSTATION
-----------------
HP-ABC-DE-01
```

In the output I want to put an empty line after "Changed database context to 'master'". How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried putting a `SELECT ''` after the `GO` statement? Or maybe `PRINT ''`?

Comment: @TimJarosz the `SELECT ''` was ugly, it adds multiple empty lines and also add the **(1 rows affected)** line. The `PRINT ''` was perfect and exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Please post it as an answer and I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `PRINT '';` just after the `GO` statement.